# Oracle LISTAGG with multiple table joins

Tags: oracle, listagg

I'm using Oracle 18.c
I have a query where I join three tables.  It works fine.

```
select ae."PRIM_KEY", 
ae."EVENT_DATE",
ae."EVENT_NAME",
ac."FIRST_NAME" || ' ' || ac."LAST_NAME" "PRESENTER"
from    "AFF_EVENT_V" ae
      , "AFF_CONTACT" ac
      , "AFF_EVENT_PRESENTER" aep
where   aep."EVENT_FKEY" = ae."PRIM_KEY"
and     aep."CONTACT_FKEY" = ac."PRIM_KEY"
Order by event_date desc
;
```

The query produces results like this:

| PRIM_KEY | EVENT_DATE | EVENT_NAME | PRESENTER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 641 | 26-APR-21 | Event 99 | George Washington |
| 622 | 19-APR-21 | Event 98 | John Adams |
| 541 | 25-JAN-21 | Event 97 | Thomas Jefferson |
| 541 | 25-JAN-21 | Event 97 | James Madison |
| 521 | 18-JAN-21 | Event 96 | James Monroe |

In many cases there are multiple Presenters for a given event.  Like the Prim_Key of 541.  I'd like to group the Presenters together for a given event so that the results would look like this:

| PRIM_KEY | EVENT_DATE | EVENT_NAME | PRESENTER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 641 | 26-APR-21 | Event 99 | George Washington |
| 622 | 19-APR-21 | Event 98 | John Adams |
| 541 | 25-JAN-21 | Event 97 | Thomas Jefferson, James Madison |
| 521 | 18-JAN-21 | Event 96 | James Monroe |

I tried to use the LISTAGG function, but I can't seem to get it right.  Here's what I've tried.

```
select ae."PRIM_KEY", 
ae."EVENT_DATE",
ae."EVENT_NAME",
LISTAGG(ac."FIRST_NAME" || ' ' || ac."LAST_NAME", ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ac."LAST_NAME") as "PRESENTER"
from    "AFF_EVENT_V" ae
      , "AFF_CONTACT" ac
      , "AFF_EVENT_PRESENTER" aep
where   aep."EVENT_FKEY" = ae."PRIM_KEY"
and     aep."CONTACT_FKEY" = ac."PRIM_KEY"
Order by event_date desc
;
```

This produces an error: **ORA-00937: not a single-group group function.**
How can I use LISTAGG when I have multiple tables joined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a `GROUP BY` clause

```
select ae."PRIM_KEY", 
ae."EVENT_DATE",
ae."EVENT_NAME",
LISTAGG(ac."FIRST_NAME" || ' ' || ac."LAST_NAME", ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ac."LAST_NAME") as "PRESENTER"
from    "AFF_EVENT_V" ae
      , "AFF_CONTACT" ac
      , "AFF_EVENT_PRESENTER" aep
where   aep."EVENT_FKEY" = ae."PRIM_KEY"
and     aep."CONTACT_FKEY" = ac."PRIM_KEY"
Group BY 
ae."PRIM_KEY", 
ae."EVENT_DATE",
ae."EVENT_NAME"
Order by event_date desc
;
```

Comment: That Fixed it.  Many Thanks Luc.  I attempted a Group By clause earlier, but that failed. Thanks to you I realize that I have to include all the prior fields in the Group By clause.  Thanks!